# reverse htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

this may seem like a simple problem but I couldn't find it in the archives.

how does one reverse the effects of htmlspecialchars?

I tried something like this:

```
$trans_tbl = get_html_translation_table (HTML_ENTITIES);
$trans_tbl = array_flip ($trans_tbl);
$html = strtr ($html, $trans_tbl);
```

but it didn't work. is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Read the manual, it will tell you all functions that have something to do with the one you are looking at in the 'see also' section [this is that section for `htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php#refsect1-function.htmlspecialchars-seealso)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be found in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use `htmlspecialchars_decode()`

```
<?php
$str = "<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>\n";

echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);

// note that here the quotes aren't converted
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES);
?>
```

Reference - [PHP Official Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Answer (score 4):

You need `htmlspecialchars_decode()`. See [PHP docu on this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php).

```
$html = htmlspecialchars_decode( $html, ENT_NOQUOTES );
```

Answer (score 4):

example :

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars('your "strange" text with characters like !"/$%?&*'))
```

it will echo : 
your "strange" text with characters like !"/$%?&*

this is an example of encode/decode. it works.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you need `htmlspecialchars_decode` - [Docu](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)