# How to convert htmlspecialchars into normal text?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've got an mySQL database and I'm using htmlspecial chars to format text before insertion... I've got: `$firstname= htmlspecialchars("O'brian", ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');`

And if I `echo $firstname;` I get `O&#039;brian`

How can I convert the value back to normal text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [reverse htmlspecialchars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257232/reverse-htmlspecialchars)

Comment: You can use `html_entity_decode()`. Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Note that `htmlspecialchars` does not protect against SQL injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `html_entity_decode()` function.

It decodes **ALL** html entities.

DO NOT USE `htmlspecialchars_decode()`!!! It won't work for things like `&#65;`.

Try this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode('&#65;'), html_entity_decode('&#65;');
```

It should output `&#65;A`.

[**Documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: @user2721465 You are welcome. Notice that to use this function, you will find that using `htmlentities()` is more useful, instead of `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: The asker explicitly specified that he wants to perform the inverse of a `htmlspecialchars` call, rather than having to decode arbitrary HTML entities like `&#65;`. Given that condition, the warning against using `htmlspecialchars_decode()` seems wrong - it will work fine for the OP's use case.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) function.

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($firstname, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 1):

There exists an opposite function called `htmlspecialchars_decode()` that you can use to convert back to normal text. You can find documentation on it in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php).