# Output a part of URL in php

Tags: php, urldecode

So, I have dynamically generated pages that follows the following format:

```
 http://example.com/name/first_name/last_name/John%2C+Smith
```

What is the php code to output the last part of the url?

so, it becomes like "John, Smith".

Thank you so much.

EDIT:

I realized that the URL is ended with another `/` and the answers given below does not pick it up. What change should I make?

```
http://example.com/name/first_name/last_name/John%2C+Smith/
```

EDIT 2:

So, the link is dynamically generated as the following:

```
href="http://example.com/name/first_name/last_name/<?php echo $full_name ?>"
```

Comment: I think this has been answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257232/reverse-htmlspecialchars]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `parse_url` with second parameter `PHP_URL_PATH`

```
$url = urldecode("http://example.com/name/first_name/last_name/John%2C+Smith");
$arr = array_filter(explode('/',parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)));
print_r(end($arr));
```

**Edited:**

As per requirement for dynamic url you can use

```
$url = urldecode("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
```

Comment: explode returns an array according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php. You really should not call the array - $str.

Comment: That's a simple variable that I've used over so for better convenience I'll update it to $arr @gene

Comment: I realized that there is a `/` at the end and I was wondering what change I should make it order for the code to work. Thank you.

Comment: Check my updated answer I've placed `array_filter` function

Comment: I have a question. The url is dynamically generated such that last part is always different, for example `http://example.com/name/first_name/last_name/Mike%2C+Tyson/`. In this case, would the answer above work? (I edited my question, see `EDIT 2` please)

Comment: Hi. so, the answer itself works good. However, the output is stuck at "John, Smith" even when the page is at "Mike, Tyson". How can I change the `$url` variable so that it picks up the last part of the url? (for example, `/John%2C+Smith/` or `/Mike%2C+Tyson/`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82662/discussion-between-uchiha-and-steve-kim).

Comment: This answer worked like a charm. I am not sure why there is a downvote on it.

Answer (score 1):

Split the url, get the last fragment then URL decode it:

```
<?
$urlarray=explode("/",$url);
$end=$urlarray[count($urlarray)-1];
$end=urldecode($end);
//go on using $end then
?>
```

Comment: You could run `array_reverse` as well, simplify a step, `$urlarray=array_reverse(explode("/",$url));
echo urldecode($urlarray[0]);`.

Comment: Just noticed that the url is ended with another `/` ("/John%2C+Smith/"). What change should I make so that it works? (I updated the question)

Comment: @steveKim  `$url = trim($url, '/');` before `explode`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a regex.

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~.*/(.*)~', 
     function($matches) { 
          return urldecode($matches[1]);
     },
     'http://example.com/name/first_name/last_name/John%2C+Smith');
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/bE3bO5/1

Output:

> John, Smith

Update:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~.*/(.+)~', 
function($matches) { 
     return rtrim(urldecode($matches[1]), '/');
},
'http://example.com/name/first_name/last_name/John%2C+Smith/');
```

Comment: I realized that there is a `/` at the end and I was wondering what change I should make it order for the code to work. Thank you.

Comment: Update written that should account for `/` or no `/` at the end.

Comment: I have a question. The url is dynamically generated such that last part is always different, for example `http://example.com/name/first_name/last_name/Mike%2C+Tyson/`. In this case, would the answer above work? (I edited my question, see `EDIT 2` please)

Comment: Yes this would work, also with or without the trailing slash. Give it a try.